# When are Python threads fast?

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

We're all aware of the horrors of the [GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock), and I've seen a lot of discussion about the right time to use the `multiprocessing` module, but I still don't feel that I have a good intuition about when threading in Python (focusing mainly on CPython) is the right answer.

What are instances in which the GIL is not a significant bottleneck?  What are the types of use cases where threading is the most appropriate answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Threading really only makes sense if you have a lot of blocking I/O going on. If that's the case, then some threads can sleep while other threads work. If threads are CPU-bound, you're not likely to see much benefit from multithreading.

Note that the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module, while more difficult to code for, makes use of separate processes and therefore doesn't suffer the downsides of the GIL.

Comment: I agree with Michael answer. Threads are enough for example for simple network operations, gathering input from user or updating GUI forms while doing some work in background. I use it quite often for such tasks. What I want to add for this answer is my experience with multiprocessing module. I almost doesn't use this module. Every time I want to use it that means I need full CPU power for a longer period of time. So I start thinking how to optimize this and finally I end up writing C/C++ module for python. In this C/C++ module I place all critical multithread code.

Comment: @mklauber Even on multicore machines, only one thread can execute at at time. This is a consequence of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) in CPython.

Comment: @Michael Mior, you're absolutely correct, I completely confused the GIL.  Editing/deleting the incorrect comment now.

Comment: Is it reasonable to think there are cases when a set of io-bound tasks are better suited for `multiprocessing` over threading?  I would think that there could be instances where the overhead of a context switch is not so bad in comparison to the overhead caused by the GIL.

Comment: @mvanveen If you have a large number of I/O bound threads where several will be unblocked at any particular time, then yes. Really, the best way to find out is to measure :)

Answer (score 10):

Since you seem to be looking for examples, here are some off the top of my head and grabbed from searching for CPU-bound and I/O-bound examples (I can't seem to find many). I am no expert, so please feel free to correct anything I've miscategorized. It's also worth noting that advancing technology could move a problem from one category to another.

### CPU Bound Tasks (use `multiprocessing`)

- Numerical methods/approximations for mathematical functions (calculating digits of pi, etc.)
- Image processing
- Performing convolutions
- Calculating transforms for graphics programming (possibly handled by GPU)
- Audio/video compression/decompression

### I/O Bound Tasks (`threading` is probably OK)

- Sending data across a network
- Writing to/reading from the disk
- Asking for user input
- Audio/video streaming

Answer (score 2):

The GIL prevents *python* from running multiple threads.

If your code releases the GIL before jumping into a C extension, other python threads can continue while the C code runs. Like with the blocking IO, that other people have mentioned.

[Ctypes does this automatically](http://www.caswenson.com/past/2009/6/13/bypassing_the_python_gil_with_ctypes/), and [so does numpy](http://www.scipy.org/ParallelProgramming). So if your code uses them a lot, it may not be significantly restricted by the GIL.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the CPU bound and I/O bound tasks, there is still more use cases. For example, thread enables **concurrent tasks**. A lot of GUI programming fall into this category. The main loop have to be responsive to mouse events. So anytime you have a task that take a while and you don't want to freeze the UI, you do it on a separate thread. It is less about performance and more about parallelism.