# No gain from multiple threads when using ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to simulate some processes in order to get some statistics. I decided to write simulation program using multiple threads as each test run is independant.

It means that if I need to perform e.g. 1000 test runs then it should be possible to have 4 threads (each doing 250 test runs).

While doing this I found that addition of multiple threads does not decrease simulation time.

I have Windows 10 laptop with 4 physical cores.

I wrote a simple program which shows behaviour I'm talking about.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time
import psutil
import random


def runScenario():
    d = dict()
    for i in range(0, 10000):
        rval = random.random()
        if rval in d:
            d[rval] += 1
        else:
            d[rval] = 1
    return len(d)    

def runScenarioMultipleTimesSingleThread(taskId, numOfCycles):
    print('starting thread {}, numOfCycles is {}'.format(taskId, numOfCycles))

    sum = 0
    for i in range(numOfCycles):
        sum += runScenario()

    print('thread {} finished'.format(taskId))

    return sum

def modelAvg(numOfCycles, numThreads):

    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=numThreads)

    cyclesPerThread = int(numOfCycles / numThreads)
    numOfCycles = cyclesPerThread * numThreads

    futures = list()
    for i in range(numThreads):
        future = pool.submit(runScenarioMultipleTimesSingleThread, i, cyclesPerThread)
        futures.append(future)

    sum = 0
    for future in futures:
        sum += future.result()

    return sum / numOfCycles


def main():
    p = psutil.Process()
    print('cpus:{}, affinity{}'.format(psutil.cpu_count(), p.cpu_affinity() ))

    start = time.time()
    modelAvg( numOfCycles = 10000, numThreads = 4)
    end = time.time()

    print('simulation took {}'.format(end - start))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

These are the results:

One thread:

```
cpus:8, affinity[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
starting thread 0, numOfCycles is 10000
thread 0 finished
simulation took 23.542529582977295
```

Four threads:

```
cpus:8, affinity[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
starting thread 0, numOfCycles is 2500
starting thread 1, numOfCycles is 2500
starting thread 2, numOfCycles is 2500
starting thread 3, numOfCycles is 2500
thread 1 finished
thread 2 finished
thread 0 finished
thread 3 finished
simulation took 23.508538484573364
```

I expect that when using 4 threads simulation time should be ideally 4 times smaller, and of cause it should not be the same.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Related: [When are Python threads fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994438/when-are-python-threads-fast), [How to get a faster speed when using multi-threading in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154487/how-to-get-a-faster-speed-when-using-multi-threading-in-python),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using cPython, you won't get significant speedups by distributing computational load across threads. This is because memory accesses in cPython are serialized using the [Python GIL mechanism](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) (Global Interpreter Lock). I have experienced this when processing text for example.

In this case, if you monitor your CPU, you would likely see that your process is not fully utilizing 4 of them, just 25% of each.

You can use [MultiProcessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html) to really spread your load across CPUs.

Threads can still provide performance improvements in Python when your threads are IO-bound (as opossed to CPU-bound).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. ProcessPoolExecutor really does what I expect.